# switch to a different user

Tags: redhat, su

I'm trying to SSH into a server then switch to a user named "jenkins". As you can see from the commands below, after I run `su - jenkins` I am still in the root user's home dir, and `whoami` indicates that I am still root, even though `su` doesn't return an error

```
don@Don-MacBook-Air:~$ ssh root@perkins.corp.foo
root@perkins.corp.foo's password: 
Last login: Thu Jan  8 03:02:23 2015 from 10.0.16.57
root@perkins.corp.foo:~ $ whoami
root
root@perkins.corp.foo:~ $ su - jenkins
root@perkins.corp.foo:~ $ whoami
root
root@perkins.corp.foo:~ $ pwd
/root
```

I've verified that there is a user named `jenkins` so I don't understand why this is failing. The server is running Red Hat 4.4.7-4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would assume your jenkins is "disabled" by setting it's shell to /bin/false. Try to set the shell to /bin/bash (f.e.)

```
chsh -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

then your su should work.

Or use

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```